# How to search for a value in the deep nested python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### I would like to know if the below code to find value from any deep nested dict(in general) is having any flaws.

Note:

> I am trying to develop generic method to fetch any value from the given dictionary.
> If the value is present, method will return True otherwise False

### Or is there any better solution to find any value

#### main function

```
def find_value(each_consumed_data, search_value):
    for key, value in each_consumed_data.items():
        if value == search_value:
            logger.debug("got the value {}".format(value))
            return True
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            from_inner_dict = __find_value_from_dict(value, search_value)
            if not from_inner_dict:
                continue
            else:
                return from_inner_dict
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            from_inner_list = __find_value_from_list(value, search_value)
            if not from_inner_list:
                continue
            else:
                return from_inner_list
        elif value != search_value:
            continue
    return False
```

#### method1 called in the main function

```
def __find_value_from_dict(nested_dict_data, search_value):
    for each_key, each_value in nested_dict_data.items():
        if each_value == search_value:
            logger.debug("got the value {}".format(each_value))
            return True
        elif isinstance(each_value, dict):
            return __find_value_from_dict(each_value, search_value)
        elif isinstance(each_value, list):
            from_list = __find_value_from_list(each_value, search_value)
            if not from_list:
                continue
            else:
                return from_list
        elif each_value != search_value:
            continue
    return False
```

#### method2 called in the main function

```
def __find_value_from_list(nested_list_data, search_value):
    """
    :param nested_list_data:
    :param search_value:
    :return:
    """
    for each_value in nested_list_data:
        if each_value == search_value:
            logger.debug("got the value {}".format(each_value))
            return True
        elif isinstance(each_value, dict):
            from_dict = __find_value_from_dict(each_value, search_value)
            if not from_dict:
                continue
            else:
                return from_dict
        elif isinstance(each_value, list):
            return __find_value_from_list(each_value, search_value)
        elif each_value != search_value:
            continue
    return False
```

*I have tested with below data. It works fine*

```
data = {'json_data': {'timestamp': '2020-11-14T11:24:14.085102Z',
                               'source': 'dfdfdfs',
                               'type': 'send-invitation-action',
                               'id': 'eca0d90a-7afe-40f1-a2f6-2204f2a2a7de',
                               'version': '1.00',
                               'payload': {'invitationCode': '385478',
                                           'invitationCodeExpiration': 1605439454.084286,
                                           'inviteeEmail': 'emailcfff',
                                           'inviteeMsisdn': None,
                                           'targetId': '259662e5-b58a-4998-97ae-0ee55cf5bc39',
                                           'targetName': ['Hello_O123','hco.v1','hello'],
                                           'invitorPersonId': '8d795bd4-e87b-4b9a-9e41-1a3f73edb45f',
                                           'invitorPersonName': 'cdfdfs'}},
                 'topic': 'hco.h',
                 'partition': 0,
                 'offset': 26}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_value(data, '385478'))
```

Comment: this seems correct. I wrote something very similar when flattening JSONL for ingest into a database table, which required keeping track of the path to the element which contained each value along with the type. As with most Python things, this will be slow.

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much for your feedback. Yes I do feel this will be slow.